# Side by Side when the window resized

Tags: html, css

i want to position the select and input tags side by side (in one line ) even when the window resized to smaller size in width the select tag not break to second line!

take a look at [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karim_medusa/3fusnt9h/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="company" />
    <select>
        <option>test 1</option>
        <option>test 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input { 
    width: 10%;
    float:right;
    margin-right:4px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
select {
    width: 80%;
    float:right;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: @ Danield , when the window resized (smaller space) select tag break into new line!

Comment: so what should happen for narrow widths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of CSS [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function to subtract the sum of your fixed box-sizes:

```
input {
    width: calc(10% - 17px);  
    ...
```

and

```
select {
    width: calc(80% - 13px);
    ...
```

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fusnt9h/5/)

Comment: tnx this answer feed what i need

Answer (score 0):

`Total width` must be 100% maximum. You have 90% in `% percentage based width`, plus `margins` and `paddings` in `pixels`. You can't accurately know what's the sum of your `total width`.

[Read about box-model](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) to understand the problem.

There are a couple of ways to deal with this:

1. Change `margins` and `paddings` to `% percents`, so that sum is `100% max`.
2. Change elements to be `box-sizing: border-box;`. Additionally, wrap them to support margins and advanced layout options.

Check this to get deeper explanation and examples:
http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: tnx for the box-sizing and the links